# Updating `current_sign_in_at` and `last_sign_in_at` in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using my own custom sign in logic using bcrypt. However I like to update two attributes (`current_sign_in_at` and `last_sign_in_at`) in my database. So, I followed the logic defined in Devise Gem to factor my solution.

The way Devise Gem implement this in [Devise::Models::Trackable.update_tracked_fields!](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/trackable.rb) and invoked as a Warden callback in [devise/hooks/trackable.rb](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb). However, following those two implementations doesn't do anything to the database upon sign in.

So do I need a callback or something inside the controller to call this? **Or to better ask my question how do I update `current_sign_in_at` and `last_sign_in_at` in my database upon a user sign in?**

**Note** am not using Devise Gem for user authentication, am only following their robust implementation.

Comment: Why not just do the update in your SessionsController or whatever handles sign-ins?

Comment: @max can you explain further or show me a logic you are referring to using SessionsController?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to simply update the timestamps in your sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController 
  def create
    # simple example using has_secure_password
    @user = User.find_by(params[:email]) 
    if @user and @user.authenticate(params[:password])  
      @user.update(
        current_sign_in_at: Time.current,
        last_sign_in_at: Time.current
      )
      redirect_to root_path, success: 'You have been logged in'
    else
      render :new, error: 'Incorrect email or password'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sure, it way be more elegant to do this with a warden callback but this is a simple solution that is easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a method to update the current_sign_in_at and last_sign_in_at in the controller and call it in the after_action for the corresponding sign_in action

For example if sign_in is the method that is called when user sign_in then

```
after_action:update_current_sign_in only: %i(sign_in)
```